# Data base - not populating the objects

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a got an issue on SQL Server Database as it is not getting objects (missing + sign to expand to get objects) and sorry, my company policy not accepting to post images so I am presenting GUI in code

SSMS 2008 view as

```
Server
     - Databases
       + System Databases
       + Database Snapshots
         [DB1]  (missing expansion + sign to get all the objects)
       + [DB2]  (DB2 is as normal)
```

Thanks
prav

Comment: Will this query produce any output for you if you execute it in a new query window: `SELECT * FROM DB1.sys.objects WHERE type <> 'S'`?

Comment: I have solved this problem, Basically got the issue with mdf and ldf files so did restoring of backups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing security rights?
Maybe your user does not have rights to read the database objects

Comment: The User has permissions, User lost connection all of a sudden, still not sure...